# can you help me find the dnf of this expression ? i got messy

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, disjunctive-normal-form

I want to find the DNF of the following expression but it got all messy.

I also tried it in wolfram alpha, and of course it showed i really need the steps you need to make to get there $\dots$

This is the table I got:  [disjunctive normal form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTA91.jpg)

$$\boxed{\begin{array}{cccc}x&y&z&f(x,y,z)\\\text{T}&\text{T}&\text{T}&\text{T}\\\text{T}&\text{T}&\text{F}&\text{T}\\\text{T}&\text{F}&\text{T}&\text{T}\\\text{T}&\text{F}&\text{F}&\text{T}\\\text{F}&\text{T}&\text{T}&\text{F}\\\text{F}&\text{T}&\text{F}&\text{T}\\\text{F}&\text{F}&\text{T}&\text{F}\\\text{F}&\text{F}&\text{F}&\text{F}\end{array}}$$

any ideas to how this could be done ?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post and explain what is DNF?

Comment: cant really explain, English is not my native, but

Comment: Disjunctive normal form (dnf) is the normalization of a logical formula in Boolean mathematics. In other words, a logical formula is said to be in disjunctive normal form if it is a disjunction of conjunctions with every variable and its negation is present once in each conjunction

Comment: You can try to use a [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map)

Comment: i dont know how to use kmap

Comment: and i have to look at all rows that ends with T then find those rows, take the x,y, and z values from each respective column then find the dnf, beacuse thats how that want me to do it ....

Comment: Take all the rows with truth value $\top$ and connect them with $\lor$ this gives you the DNF of the expression, but in this case it's not the Minimal DNF.